# Configure Apache 2.4.9 to access on LAN

Tags: windows-8.1, apache-http-server, lan, wamp

I have Apache 2.4.9 installed on Windows 8.1 system. I have configured `httpd.config` :

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
Listen [::0]:80
..
..
<Directory />
   AllowOverride none
   Require all denied
   Allow from all
</Directory>
..
..
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
   AllowOverride all
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
   Require local
</Directory>
```

and `phpmyadmin.conf` files as below:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/apps/phpmyadmin4.1.14/">
  Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
  AllowOverride all
  Order Deny,Allow
  Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I am able to access `phpmyadmin` on another system but not other projects. I am getting this error -

---

**Forbidden**

*You don't have permission to access / on this server.*

---

I have tried almost all the methods to do this like - turning off firewall and creating new inbound firewall rule.

Please help me. Where am I making a mistake?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your configuration includes this:

```
<Directory "c:/wamp/www/">
   Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
   AllowOverride all
   Order deny,allow
   Allow from all
   Require local
</Directory>
```

That `Require local` directive limits access to the same host (i.e. localhost), as in [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/trunk/mod/mod_authz_host.html):

> The `local` provider allows access to the server if any of the
>   following conditions is true:
>
> - the client address matches 127.0.0.0/8
> - the client address is ::1
> - both the client and the server address of the connection are the same
>
> This allows a convenient way to match connections that originate from
>   the local host:
>
> ```
> Require local
> ```

Comment: Changed it to `Require all granted`, worked like charm. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- on apatch menu open http-vhosts.config

  change
  Require local
  to
  Require all granted
- after that on apatch httpd.config

  search
  `<Directory/>`

  `</Directory>`
   make this inside

  ```
   Order deny,allow  
      Allow from all
  ```